# Convert Expect script to Pexpect to allow Enter key

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

I've a perfectly working expect script that I'm trying to convert to python using expect or subprocess. I've created it using `autoexpect`.

It just wait for password prompt and ignore it by pressing Enter key:

```bash
set timeout -1
spawn ./electron-cash --dir ""  create
match_max 100000
expect -exact "Password (hit return if you do not wish to encrypt your wallet):"
send -- "\r"
expect eof
```

However when I tried to do the same using `pexpect` I had all different type of issues. Either it stuck with no response or just shows nothing and close.

Here is what I came up with but it hangs doing nothing:

```py
import pexpect 
import sys

python_exec = "/home/user/electron-cash-wallet/venv/bin/python"
command = "/home/user/electron-cash-wallet/src/Electron-Cash/electron-cash"


p = pexpect.spawn(python_exec, [command, "--scalenet", "create"])
# ~ p.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer 

p.expect("Password (hit return if you do not wish to encrypt your wallet):")

p.sendline(b'\r')

p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

I'm using Python 3

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36145276/how-to-prevent-pexpect-from-echoing-the-password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, it was an issue with commenting the parentheses in the expected message.

Changed to this:

```
p.expect("Password \(hit return if you do not wish to encrypt your wallet\):")
```

### Full code:

```py
import pexpect 
import sys
import os

home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')

python_exec = home_dir + "/dev/electron-cash-wallet/venv/bin/python"
command = home_dir + "/dev/electron-cash-wallet/src/Electron-Cash/electron-cash"
network = "scalenet"


p = pexpect.spawn(python_exec, [command, "--scalenet", "create"])
# ~ p.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer 

p.expect("Password \(hit return if you do not wish to encrypt your wallet\):")

p.sendline(b'\r')

p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Here is a more advanced and verbose version in function:

```py
import pexpect 
import sys
import os

home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')

python_exec = home_dir + "/electron-cash-wallet/venv/bin/python"
ec_exec = home_dir + "/electron-cash-wallet/src/Electron-Cash/electron-cash"
network = "scalenet"

def create_wallet(python_exec, ec_exec, network):
    print("Python: ", python_exec)
    print("Electron Cash: ", ec_exec)
    # Execute the command
    p = pexpect.spawn(python_exec, [ec_exec, f"--{network}", "create"])
    # Verbose, show messages
    p.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer
    p.delaybeforesend = 2
    print("Exceution done")
    # Expect the response
    p.expect("Password \(hit return if you do not wish to encrypt your wallet\):")
    print("Expected input received")
    p.delaybeforesend = 1
    # Send return key
    p.sendline(b'\r')
    print("Sent response")
    p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
    print("Script done")

create_wallet(python_exec, ec_exec, network)
```